# jenkins-job-builder doesn't propagate a variable value

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

I am using **[jenkins-job-builder](http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/)** to create my pipeline project. But I have a problem with the variables values when I am trying to reuse or propagating.

It is my project configuration:

```
- project:
    name: myproject
    git_url: git@gitlabserver.cu:demos-products/myproject.git

    jobs:
      - '{name}-nfr-smoke-tests':
          pipeline-next: '{name}-nfr-smoke-tests'
```

And here is my **[job-template](http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/configuration.html#job-template)**:

```
- job-template:
    name: "{name}-nfr-smoke-tests"
    node: 'slave1'
    scm:
      - git:
          skip-tag: false
          url: 'git@gitlabserver.cu:test-products/{name}-nfr-tests.git'
          branches:
            - master
          wipe-workspace: true
    builders:
      - shell: |
          bundle install
          bundle exec cucumber features/smoke.feature

    publishers:
      - trigger:
          project: "{pipeline-next}"
          threshold: SUCCESS
```

Ok, now when I run this configuration in jenkins and I check the job's construction, it says:

```
No such project ‘{name}-nfr-smoke-tests’. Did you mean ‘myproject-nfr-smoke-tests’?
```

Why the line: `pipeline-next: '{name}-nfr-smoke-tests'`doesn't propagates the value of variable **name** and just used it as a **literal** string? I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'name' under 'project' section in your job-template. Append the following lines:

```
- project:
   name: project-name
```

The purpose of a project is to collect related jobs together, and provide values for the variables in a Job Template.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Jenkins Job Builder version 0.9.0-0.2 does not propagate the value, but for me version 1.3.0+2015.12.15.git136.959eb4b909-1 did. Perhaps updating your version of Jenkins Job Builder might help?